# Error while data loading to salesforce

Tags: data-loader

I am trying to do data loading to salesforce which has Date field but it is giving the following error.

> INVALID_FIELD:Failed to deserialize field at col 1. Due to,
>   '02/01/2019' is not a valid value for the type xsd:date:Date__c

how can i resolve this error and upload data?

Comment: Either use YYYY/MM/DD format while uploading the date OR it should match with the user's locale.

Answer (score 3):

there is a nice article about [CSV 'Date' and 'Date Time' format in Data Loader and API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004680&language=en_US&type=1).

Regarding `Date` type:

> "Date" field acceptable formats
>   YYYY-MM-DD
>
> YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
>
> YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
>
> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
>
> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ

So change `02/01/2019` to `2019-01-02`

---

I recommend you to always use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. I think almost all APIs can work with this standard.